# Ask user input and a command to continue or stop. After user wants program to stop, it give user the max and min value entered during the program?

Tags: c

[Question and example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dIow.png)

I am trying to code a program that would ask the user to input a number, and then ask if the user wants to continue. If the response is "yes" then the program will ask for the user input again. If the response is "no" then the program will stop and give the user the maximum and minimum value that the user input during the program running.

This is my take on the problem, its still incomplete and probably very wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float value, command, max, min;
    int a[100];
    
    printf("Please enter the value: ");
    scanf("%f",value);
    
    printf("Do you want to continue?: ");
    scanf("%f",command);
    
    if (!strcmp(command, "yes")){
    printf("Please enter the value: ");
    scanf("%f",value);
    printf("Do you want to continue?: ");
    scanf("%f",command);    
    }
    
    if (!strcmp(command, "no")){
    max = a[0];
    min = a[0];

    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>max)
        {
            max = a[i];
        }


        if(a[i]<min)
        {
            min = a[i];
        }
    }
    } 
    
    printf("The maximum value is %f, and the minumum is %f",max,min);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Protip:** `scanf("%f",value);` it should be `scanf("%f",&value);` (notice an ampersand sign).

Comment: Why is `command` a `float`? It should be a string. Furthermore, compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and read the warnings.

Comment: Tip: `scanf("%f",value);` should have generated a warning.  Save time.  Enable all warnings or use a better compiler.

Answer (score 0):

- To handle an arbitrary number of inputs, use a loop and test for a new minimum and maximum within.
- The `scanf` conversion specification `%f` needs the address of `value`.
- We can't scan the `command` string into a `float`.
- The given output format for the numbers we get with the `printf` conversion specification `%g`.

E. g.:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float value, max = FLT_MIN, min = FLT_MAX;
    char command[4];
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter the value : "); scanf("%f", &value);
        if (value > max) max = value;
        if (value < min) min = value;
        printf("Do you want to continue : "); scanf("%3s", command);
    } while (strcmp(command, "no") != 0);
    printf("The maximum value was %g and the minumum is %g\n", max, min);
}
```

Note that the example code is not safe for wrong input.